# On/Off Event on Same Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a toggle button that works with CSS but I need to add some logic when it's on and when it's off. The problem is jQuery cannot read the :after and :before on CSS because they're not actually part of the DOM.

--TOGGLE--

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span id="switch-inner" class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

--CSS--

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 78px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #C2C2C2; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 28px; padding: 0; line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #5C7FE3; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 18px; margin: 5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 46px;
    border: 2px solid #C2C2C2; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

I tried the onClick event but everytime I click it (logically) it fires the code (multiple times if clicked multiple times), what would be perfect is that one would be true and fire the code and in the second click it would do something else.

I don't know if this could be super simple and my brain is tired and not thinking correctly, but any help would be helpful!!

Comment: What is the exact behavior you want it to do when it's "on" vs. "off"? (It's a lot of CSS and it would be easier for us if you include a simple example to show what you want to do)

Comment: If you want to store information in an element, you can use [`data-*` attributes](https://api.jquery.com/data/), or (if it's just styles you want to turn on/off) [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) a CSS class. Links to jQuery docs for these two functions provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `click` event handler is the right approach. Simply look at the `checked` property of the checkbox to know the state of the button (on/off).

```js
document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").addEventListener("click", function(){
   // Test the state of the checkbox and act accordingly
   if(this.checked){
     console.log("ON");
   } else {
     console.log("OFF");
   }
});
```

```css
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 78px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #C2C2C2; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 28px; padding: 0; line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #5C7FE3; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 18px; margin: 5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 46px;
    border: 2px solid #C2C2C2; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span id="switch-inner" class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG, I cannot believe I didn't catched that!! thank you so much!!!!!! :))